Ac clutch not engaging 98 dodge ram 1500
I have a 98 dodge ram 1500 with the 5.2 L V-8 engine just replaced the AC compressor noticed that the clutch is not engaging. What do you think the problem may be?

What other work was performed in repairing this system? Please include details.

No other work has been done.

A friend of mine who is a Dodge Ram of a different year and model won't engage his A/C clutch if the low side refrigerant pressure is too low. If your Dodge Ram has this same feature and most of the refrigerant has escaped due to a leak, that would explain the clutch not engaging. Suggest you return to the mechanic who changed the compressor and have them test pressure and check for leaks.
